# Using tempfile to create a sub-directory for all of my tempfiles

Tags: python, temporary-files

I've been using `tempfile.mkdtemp` with a prefix to create my temp files. This results in a lot of different directory in my tmp folder with '`tmp/myprefix{uniq-string}/`'.

I would like to change this and have a subdirectory so that my the temp folders I create are all under one main directory so that the prefix is actually a subfolder of `tmp` '`tmp/myprefix/{uniq-string}/`'.

Also, I don't want to override `tempfile`'s system for defining a default tmp directory.

I tried playing with the '`prefix`' and '`dir`' parameters but with no success.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To use the dir argument you have to ensure the dir folder exists.  Something like this should work:

```
import os
import tempfile

#define the location of 'mytemp' parent folder relative to the system temp
sysTemp = tempfile.gettempdir()
myTemp = os.path.join(sysTemp,'mytemp')

#You must make sure myTemp exists
if not os.path.exists(myTemp):
    os.makedirs(myTemp)

#now make your temporary sub folder
tempdir = tempfile.mkdtemp(suffix='foo',prefix='bar',dir=myTemp)

print tempdir
```

Comment: I forgot about gettempdir(). Thanks!

Comment: actually, by `os.makedirs(myTemp, exist_ok=True)`, you can drop the if check by yourself

Comment: The exist_ok parameter was added at [3.2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs)

Answer (score 1):

Works for me. Did you create the `tmp` folder beforehand?

```
>>> import tempfile
>>> tempfile.mkdtemp(dir="footest", prefix="fixpre")
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'footest/fixpregSSaFg'
```

Looks like it does try to create a subfolder of `footest`....